# Reference dynamically created component in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I know I can create a reference to my component in my view model like this:

.html:

```
<template>
  <mdfield view-model.ref="ref"></mdfield>
</template>
```

.ts:

```
export class Vm {
  ref: any;

  test(){
   console.log(this.ref);
  }
}
```

This works, but what is the syntax if I'm creating the components dynamically? Like this:

```
<template>
  <div repeat.for="field of fields">
     <mdfield view-model.ref="<what goes here?>"></mdfield>
  </div>
</template>
```

I guess I want to add them to an array in my viewmodel for later reference, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$index` gives you the current index of the `repeat.for`. So, if you want to add the view-model references to an array:

```
<div repeat.for="field of fields">
    <mdfield view-model.ref="refArray[$index]"></mdfield>
</div>
```